# How to validate against related objects in Django admin?

Tags: django, validation, foreign-keys

We have two simple models:

```
class Master(models.Model):
    pass

class Detail(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to validate that the order of all details for a master are a sequence from one up, e.g. three details means 1, 2, 3.

I tried in Master.clean(), but I cant see how to access the details if they have been changed on a master-detail page.

Now I am trying to do it in an admin form for Master, but I have the same problem there, how can I access the modified datail data? Besides that, I would prefer to do the check somewhere in the model, so I don't have to repeat myself for other forms.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way is getting help from transaction in validation. for example:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def save_form(self, master, details):
   # Save or update master instance and details list
   if not is_sequence(): # check sequences in details.
        raise Exception('invalid')
```

Then instead of using form's save method, use this method anywhere that is needed, or just override form's save method with this.

Implementation isn't important, I just want to propose idea of using transaction. In this way you save all values in databases so in your is_sequence() you can easily access the details also you validate them before commiting this transaction and if it weren't valid roll-back occurs.

Comment: This could be a way indeed. But commit_on_success is deprecated since Django 1.5?

Comment: As described in [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#transactions-upgrading-from-1-5) you can use transaction.atomic decorator instead.